# Adding Component to a Parent Container by ActionEvent of a JButton in Child Panel

Tags: java, swing, containers, actionlistener

I have a JFrame(frm) in which I've added a JPanel (pnl1)..which in turn has another JPanel(pnl2) inside.. Now I have a JButton (btnThrow) in the pnl2.... Is it possible to add/modify the Objects in  frm by clicking btnThrow....
I mean how can I modify/add parent container's components?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Have you read the [tutorial on the Swing layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) yet? Most of this is spelled out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know how to add components to a container according to your question. So the only thing that remains is to do this when the button is clicked, which can be achieved by adding an `ActionListener` to the button (`JButton#addActionListener`). To find the parent in your listener you can either pass a reference to it, or use the `ActionEvent#getSource` and then search for the parent (`Component#getParent`). Personally, I would pass a reference